# GNU Make: A better way of using both C/C++ targets with different commands

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Q: Here is my Makefile fragment below:

```
SRCS+=$(wildcard *.c *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)))
# .....
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Werror $(INC) $(C_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Werror $(INC) $(C_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

How can I refactor expression after "OBJECTS" and remove duplication of the similar rules for .cpp and .%c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(basename $(SRCS)))
# Note that you may not need this variable at all.

COMPILE_ARGS = -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Werror $(INC) $(C_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(COMPILE_ARGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(COMPILE_ARGS)
```

Comment: The macros is an interesting solution. Thanks!

Comment: You missed the alternation on `$(CC)` and `$(CXX)`.

Comment: Yes. It's important for me

Comment: After I made my edit, I saw that I had come up with exactly the same solution as @EtanReisner for the commands.

Comment: Yup, deleted my answer because you had the `basename` solution which was better than mine was going to have been.